# Getting index of string

Tags: c, string, loops

My code is as follows:

```
cc_string = "378282246310005"
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(cc_string); i < (n / 2); i++)
     {
         index = cc_string[i];
         sum += (index * 2);
         printf("%i\n", sum);
     }
```

but my output is always (every number in the string is added together):

```
102
212
324
424
536
636
736
```

instead of:

```
22
38
42
50
56
56
56
```

Comment: type of `cc_string`?

Comment: (How) Did you initialized `sum`?

Comment: `int sum += (index * 2);` .... `sum` starts not initialized.... Declare it before loop, initialized to 0, and use it inside loop.

Comment: Take the character `'1'`, it is ***not*** equal to the `int` value `1`. In other words `'1' != 1`. Reading e.g. [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (ASCII being the most common character encoding) should help you.

Comment: `int sum;` should be located outside the 'for' loop, and, as said before, it should be initialized.

Comment: @LPs Actually, should that even *compile*?

Comment: @LPs It was initialised, I made a mistake when copying

Comment: Well, BTW @Someprogrammerdude comment hit the point, I guess.

Comment: How nice of you to invalidate an answer because copy and pasting is too difficult. How about a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ASCII` digits as numbers, that is not correct.

`ASCII '1'` is `0x31` Hex or `49` decimal.

So your first loop gives you `102 = '3'(0x33, 51) * 2`

To fix it simple subtract '0' to your ASCII digits:

```
index = cc_string[i] - '0';
```

Obviously the expexted output in your question does not have any sense, cause first `sum` will be `6` not, if `sum` is initialized to `0`

So expected output can be the following plus the offset of `sum` init value

```
6
20
36
40
56
60
64
```

Comment: Presumably he has initialized `sum = 0;` somewhere. May be worth including that in the `for` loop initialization as well `:)` Good answer.